# Animate Elements when they change position (Responsive Layout)

Tags: css, animation, responsive-design, positioning

Here's codepen for layout: http://codepen.io/justdade/pen/hDzAv

I want that ".small" elements float under the "#big" element instead of just jumping out there. Is this possible to make using CSS only or can you give me the idea how should I make it using JS/jQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: Try "Quicksand" it might help u achieve what u need http://razorjack.net/quicksand/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot achieve this using css alone - you're going to need to lay out the elements and change their position using javascript.

As this would be a tedious task to write from scratch, i recommend looking at libraries/plugins that do this for you.

Check out the masonry plugin at: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: http://css-tricks.com/animated-media-queries/,

you can create animations that are less laggy (on safari at least) than the masonry plugin by using css's `transition` attribute

Comment: 2 Years ago friend. Believe me, much changed. Thank for the help tho xD

Comment: Oh - haha, didn't notice date :)